# Launching the $ command line in Canopy iPython

Tags: python, ipython, canopy

How can I launch the command that begins with $ in Canopy iPython ? I am using Windows 7.

It seems such a trivial question but I tried to find an answer by googling every possible version of my question without coming close to an answer. Yet websites tutorials on iPython often ask you to enter something on a line like that.

I have no trouble with the interpreter which uses numerical in/out prompts like

```
In [23]:
Out [24]:
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, the `$` is not an IPython prompt. It is a shell prompt. Basically, the commands entered at that prompt are not IPython commands, but are commands that you enter at your terminal/command prompt. Linux distros and OSX call it the Terminal, BSD, the XTerm, and Windows, the Command Prompt.

**EDIT:** Since you are using Windows 7, you would use the Command Prompt. Some UNIX commands, like grep and awk, are UNIX-only but available for Windows using things like GNUWin. Others, like cat, have their own Command Prompt alternatives, like type.

Comment: To add to this: after you open "Command Prompt" from the start menu, you will see something like "C:\Users\levitsky\> " rather than "$"

Answer (score 0):

From the Canopy Editor, you can also start a line with an exclamation point !:

IN [1] !python

Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.6 | 64-bit | (default, Sep 15 2014, 17:43:19) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.